# How to print the result one by one from an array in golang?

Tags: arrays, go

In this code, I am finding the data based on email and password. But I want to do another thing that is to use a `for loop` and print the `result` array data one by one.

**Given result**

```
Found a single document: {Name:bilal Email:bilal@gmail.com Password:bilalo Business:computer company}
```

**Expected result**

```
Name:bilal 
Email:bilal@gmail.com 
Password:1234 
Business:computer company
```

**Code**

```
// Find data in database based on email and password
var result Store
collection := client.Database("PMS").Collection("dataStored")
if err = collection.FindOne(context.TODO(), bson.M{"email": myEmail, "password": myPassword}).Decode(&result); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Printf("Found a single document: %+v\n", result)

for _, results := range &result {
    fmt.Println(results)
}
```

Comment: 1. Can you explain your `Store` data type?
2. Is all results have same fields? (Name, Email, Password, Business)

Comment: `Store` is a struct that contains these variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `printf` before the loop

```
fmt.Printf("Name:%v \nEmail:%v \nPassword:%v \nBusiness:%v \n", result.Name, result.Email, result.Password, result.Business)
```